# Google Cloud unknown "Storage PD Capacity" charges

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-billing

Recently, a charge for "Storage PD Capacity" started showing up in Google Cloud. According to the charge, I'm using 7.27 GiB somewhere even though I don't directly use any VMs or Storage Disks.

The only Compute Engine product that I use is 1 Google Cloud Run service which has no persistent storage. My service uses a static outbound IP address which I configured using [this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip) guide. This uses a Serverless VPC Access Connector which has 2 f1-micro instances active at all times (it never scales past that). However, I don't see any mention of persistent storage used by these instances on the [pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/pricing#serverless-vpc-pricing) (nor can I think of why they would use 7GB).

The only other product I use is Google Cloud API Gateway which I don't think would need storage, especially considering it [doesn't even cache responses](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Apigee/API-Gateway-caching/m-p/170872).

The only thing that I have to go off of is that these charges started appearing on April 16. On this day, I made the following changes:

- moved my Cloud Run service from us-central1 to us-east4
- moved my API Gateway from us-central1 to us-east4
- moved my static IP address from us-central1 to us-east4, following [this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip) guide again

By "moved" I mean deleted and recreated from scratch.

$0.32 a day isn't much but just trying to understand where this storage is being used!

[image: Disks]
[image: Billing]

Comment: The VPC connector are billed as VMs and all VMs uses a disk (PD) so this is the reason. I think the pricing docs only mention that the connectors are billed as VMs and even if those imply all the possible charges of a VM the docs should clarify this. You may want to contact GCP billing support to get an official answer.

Comment: @Puteri I considered that, but as mentioned in my post I was using a VPC connector prior to Apr 16 (in us-central1 instead of us-east4) and was not seeing these charges. Also, 7 GB for 2 specialized VM instances seems like a lot

Comment: I recommend contacting Google Cloud Billing support. You are being charged for two disk instances that match the micro VM's regions. What does `view your Serverless VPC Access costs in the Google Cloud console by filtering your billing reports by the label key serverless-vpc-access` show?

Comment: It requires internal support feel free to contact [google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub).

Comment: I reached out to google support. I'll update here once I find out more. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few weeks of wasted back and forth with Google Cloud support, I was able to get to the bottom of this.

**TLDR**; Persistent Disk (PD) Storage has a free tier in us-central1 but no free tier in us-east4. So after moving VPC Serverless Access Connector to us-east4, I started getting charged for PD storage.

---

VPC serverless access connectors use [Compute Engine Instance Groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups) under the hood. Here's a screenshot from Google support (this seems to be an internal-only view as it's not visible from for me in the console): [image: VPC Serverless Access Instance Group]

These are VMs that use Persistent Disk (PD) Storage. When I switched the VPC serverless access connector from us-central1 to us-east4, the PD storage also changed: [image]

Previously, I hadn't noticed the "Storage PD Capacity" charge because it was 0. After switching to us-east4, the cost became non-zero and so I noticed it. Based on the SKUs,

- https://cloud.google.com/skus/?currency=USD&filter=D973-5D65-BAB2 shows that PD in us-central has a free tier "0.00 USD (Free) per gibibyte month, for 0 to 30 gibibyte month, per month per account"
- https://cloud.google.com/skus/?currency=USD&filter=8AF1-1146-E7DA shows that PD in us-east4 does NOT have a free tier, which is why I only started getting charged for this after migrating